# Angular 14 Http calls are calling twice

Tags: angular, httpclient

I am subscribing to the response on the controller. My API calling flow is Controller -> Service -> BaseService.

Controller code:

```
this.salesManagerService.getNotificationsCounts(token).subscribe((response:any) => {
  if(response.response.status){
    this.notifications = response;
  }
});
```

Service code:

```
public getNotificationsCounts(token:any){
return this.baseService.getCall(this.url.SALES_MANAGER_NOTIFICATIONS_COUNT + token);
```

}

BaseService code:

```
public getCall(url:any) :any{
return this.http.get<any>(url, this.httpOptions).pipe(retry(1), catchError(this.handleError));
```

}

When I call any API on the controller it's called 2 times.
[image]

Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Comment: Probably has to do with how you’re calling the service in your controller code

Answer (score 1):

```
public getCall(url:any) :any{
  return this.http.get<any>(url, this.httpOptions)
  .pipe(
    retry(1), 
    catchError(this.handleError),
    shareReplay(1)
);
```

Try **shareReplay(1)**

Comment: Same issue with shareReplay(1)

Answer (score 0):

```js
public getCall(url:any) :any{
    return this.http.get<any>(url, this.httpOptions)
      .pipe(
        tap(
          {
            next: () => {
              shareReplay();
            },
            error: (error) => {
              console.log(error);
            }
          }
        )
      )
  }
```

Hope this helps!